# Extract tree count from images-using CV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Greetings of the day.

I'm trying to extract tree count from an aerial image. The method I opted for extracting trees:

1. RGB2HSV
2. Extract Green Channel
3. Apply threshold to extract green pixels

After extracting the canopy of the tree I need to establish the point feature at the centroid of each tree. Can anybody help in this regards?
For your reference, I'm attaching the image of my last output obtained after applying threshold which contains only tree canopy.

[image: OutputImage]

Comment: would object detection from deep learning be more appropriate to solve this problem ? some trees are overlapping here, additional non-trivial steps maybe required to extricate the boundaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rather coarse approach is to count the total bright area using some average area per tree.

Anything else will cause problems due to overlap and differences in shape and size.

There is a paper I read in 2017 that covers oil palm counting using deep-learning. Maybe give this a shot.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/312161143_Deep_Learning_Based_Oil_Palm_Tree_Detection_and_Counting_for_High-Resolution_Remote_Sensing_Images

Also note that there are special band combinations that help with vegetation segmentation.

https://eos.com/color-infrared/